# PHP Variable Session Code Not Working

Tags: php, forms, variables

All pages on my bosses website initiate sessions, there is a variable on the property pages that is defined (or redefined) each time a user visits one. That variable is supposed to carry over to the contact page, where it gets inserted into the PHP contact form and sent along in an email to my boss, so that he knows which property people are contacting him about.

Here is the code I use to define the variable:

```
$_SESSION['property'] = "55-scholard-ph5";//Set Property Name
```

I have a generic PHP contact form I'm using that works fine, I also have

```
<?php // Start the session
session_start(); ?>
```

at the beginning of every page. This solution was working for about a month, but now it doesn't insert that variable.

Here is the complete HTML page code:

```
<!--FORM SESSION CODE-->
<?php

// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<!--FORM SESSION CODE-->

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1100">
<title>Boris Kholodov &#183; 55 Scollard, Penthouse 5 &#183; Toronto, Canada</title>
    <meta name="description" content="View 55 Scollard, Penthouse 5 at Boris Kholodov's real estate website.">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../design.css">


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../javajq/jquery.touchslider.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".touchslider").touchSlider({container: this,
duration: 800, // the speed of the sliding animation in milliseconds
delay: 5000, // initial auto-scrolling delay for each loop
margin: 3, // borders size. The margin is set in pixels.
mouseTouch: true,
namespace: "touchslider",
next: ".touchslider-next", // jQuery object for the elements to which a "scroll forwards" action should be bound.
pagination: ".touchslider-nav-item",
currentClass: "touchslider-nav-item-current", // class name for current pagination item.
prev: ".touchslider-prev", // jQuery object for the elements to which a "scroll backwards" action should be bound.
autoplay: true, // Activate auto-scrolling, choose either "true" or "false"
viewport: ".touchslider-viewport"});
});
</script>

</head>

<body bgcolor="#fafbff">

<!--FORM ADDRESS CODE-->
<?php
$_SESSION['property'] = "55-scholard-ph5";//Set Property Name
?>
<!--FORM ADDRESS CODE-->


<?php include('../navigation.html');?> 



<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
<div id="page-wrap">
    <!--JAVASCRIPT DISABLED NOTIFICATION-->
    <noscript>
        <?php include('../noscript.html');?> 
    </noscript>

    <!---------------------------------------- MOBILE SLIDER ---------------------------------------->

<div class="touchslider hideslide" style="text-align: center;">
    <div class="touchslider-viewport" style="width:1000px; height:550px; overflow:hidden; position: relative;"><div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/1.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/2.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/3.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/4.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/5.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/6.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/7.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/8.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/9.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>
        <div class="touchslider-item"><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/10.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></div>


    </div>
    </div>

    <br /><br />

     <!---------------------------------------- LEAVING FOR NOW, BUT DONT NEED IT ---------------------------------------->
    <div style="text-align:center; height:5px; width: 1000px; position: relative;">
        <span class="touchslider-prev" style="cursor:pointer; z-index: 40;"><span class="prevbutton"></span></span>

        <span class="touchslider-next" style="cursor:pointer; z-index: 40;"><span class="nextbutton"></span></span>
    </div>


</div> 

    <!---------------------------------------- DESKTOP SLIDER ---------------------------------------->


    <div id="container" class="hidephone" >
    <ul>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/1.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/2.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/3.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/4.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/5.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/6.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/7.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/8.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/9.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/55-scholard-ph5/10.jpg" class="round" width="1000" height="550" /></li>
    </ul>
    <span class="button prevButton"></span>
    <span class="button nextButton"></span>


    </div>  

    <img src="images/spacer.gif" class="hidephone" />


    <hr class="purple">
    <br />


    <!----------------------------------------MAIN INFO AREA-------------------------------------->
    <article>
    <section>
    <div class="lefttextbig">
        <header>
        <h1 class="black cursive">Luxury Penthouse at the Four Seasons</h1>
        <br />
        <h2 class="black">$1,950,000 &#183; 55 Scollard, Penthouse 5</h2>
        </header>
        <p class="black">
            <br />
            <span class="subtitle">CANADA'S MOST PRESTIGIOUS ADDRESS </span> &nbsp;  Yorkville. Bloor. Four Seasons. Everyone knows. This is the most prestigious and coveted address in Canada. Luxurious, stylish, seductive, the new Four Seasons Hotel Toronto has already established itself as Toronto’s most famous meeting place. Its architectural pedigree, its personality and its name have successfully attracted those from Toronto and those from abroad. 
            <br /><br />

            <span class="subtitle">ONLY THE BEST</span> &nbsp; Designed by architectsAlliance in collaboration with Page & Steele this hotel condo development demonstrates a contemporary design paired with a level of elegance that will satisfy the most discerning purchaser. The private residences offer the best in design and service.

            <br /><br />

            <span class="subtitle">360 DEGREE LUXURY</span> &nbsp; Penthouse 5 is a luxuriously finished residence, measuring 1265 precious square feet, offering you 11-foot ceilings and stunning views from floor-to-ceiling windows throughout. This suite is bright, impressive, modern, yet elegant. The layout features a discreet entrance area, an open living area, split bedrooms, 2 full baths and a 20ft balcony. 

            <br /><br />

            <span class="subtitle">ALL YOU COULD ASK FOR &mdash; AND THEN SOME</span> &nbsp; The east tower is a private, exclusive, resident-only building.  Its owners enjoy privacy coupled with easy access to all the benefits of Four Season living, including access to hotel amenities, facilities and services. Just steps away from five-star Yorkville shops and restaurants, and central Toronto metro stations. 

            <br /><br />
            To schedule a viewing <a href="listing-contact.php" class="black">contact Boris Kholodov</a>.<br /><br />

        </p>

        <hr class="purple">

        <br /><br />

        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2885.828667395075!2d-79.3884502!3d43.672532999999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x882b34aedb4fae43%3A0xedbc5eb829dd0221!2s55+Scollard+St%2C+Toronto%2C+ON+M5R!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1427829323609" width="650" height="350" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!----------------------------------------MAIN INFO AREA-------------------------------------->

    <!----------------------------------------DETAILED INFO---------------------------------------->
    <section>
     <div class="rightinfo">

             <!-- Boris's Photo, Title and Contact Info-->
                <?php include('boris-info.html');?> 


               <!-- <hr class="purple"> 

                <p class="small">
                    <span class="italic">Open House Times:</span><br />
                    Sat 28<sup>th</sup> / 2:30pm&#8211;4:30pm<br />
                    Sun 1<sup>st</sup> / 2:30pm&#8211;4:30pm
                </p> -->

                <hr class="purple">

                <a href="listing-book.php" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <div class="purpleb round formstyle bgcolor sendform" style="
                    padding: 15px 15px 8px 15px;
                    width: 210px;
                    text-align: center;">
                        <span class="parastyle black" style="font-weight: normal;
                        letter-spacing: 0.1em;">
                            BOOK A SHOWING
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </a>

                <hr class="purple">

                <a href="images/55-scholard-ph5/55-scholard-ph5-floorplan-boris.pdf" style="text-decoration: none;" target="_blank">
                    <div class="purpleb round formstyle bgcolor sendform" style="
                    padding: 15px 15px 8px 15px;
                    width: 210px;
                    text-align: center;">
                        <span class="parastyle black" style="font-weight: normal;
                        letter-spacing: 0.1em;">
                            VIEW FLOORPLAN
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </a>

                 <hr class="purple">

                <a href="listing-contact.php" style="text-decoration: none;">
                    <div class="purpleb round formstyle bgcolor sendform" style="
                    padding: 15px 15px 8px 15px;
                    width: 210px;
                    text-align: center;">
                        <span class="parastyle black" style="font-weight: normal;
                        letter-spacing: 0.1em;">
                            CONTACT BORIS
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </a>

                <hr class="purple">



                <p class="small">
                    <span class="italic">Type:</span>
                    Downtown Penthouse
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Neighbourhood:</span>
                    Yorkville
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Square Footage:</span>
                    1265<sup>sf</sup> + Balcony
                    <br />
                    <!--<span class="italic">Lot Size:</span>
                    33<sup>ft</sup> &#215; 128<sup>ft</sup>
                    <br /> -->
                    <span class="italic">Property Tax:</span>
                    $15,266 for 2014
                    <br />
                  <span class="italic">Bedrooms:</span>
                    2
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Washrooms:</span>
                    2
                    <br />
                    <span class="italic">Parking:</span>
                    1 Owned Underground
                </p>

                <hr class="purple">
                <p class="small">
                    <span class="italic">Inclusions:</span>
        <ul >                    
                    <li class="small">Miele Gas Cooktop and Oven, Sub-Zero Fridge, Panasonic Microwave, Dishwasher, Stacked Washer/Dryer</li>
                    <li class="small">All Existing Light Fixtures</li>
                    <li class="small">All Existing Window Coverings</li>
        </ul>

                    <hr class="purple">
                <p class="small">
                    To inquire further about this property please <a href="listing-contact.php" class="black">contact Boris</a>.
                </p>

            </div>
      </section>
      <!----------------------------------------DETAILED INFO---------------------------------------->
    </article>

<?php include('../footer.html');?> 


</div>
<!-- MAIN CONTENT -->


<script src="../javajq/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).load(function(){
        var pages = $('#container li'), current=0;
        var currentPage,nextPage;
        var timeoutID;
        var buttonClicked=0;

        var handler1=function(){
            buttonClicked=1;
            $('#container .button').unbind('click');
            currentPage= pages.eq(current);
            if($(this).hasClass('prevButton'))
            {
                if (current <= 0)
                    current=pages.length-1;
                    else
                    current=current-1;
            }
            else
            {

                if (current >= pages.length-1)
                    current=0;
                else
                    current=current+1;
            }
            nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
            currentPage.fadeTo('slow',0.3,function(){
                nextPage.fadeIn('slow',function(){
                    nextPage.css("opacity",1);
                    currentPage.hide();
                    currentPage.css("opacity",1);
                    $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);
                }); 
            });         
        }

        var handler2=function(){
            if (buttonClicked==0)
            {
            $('#container .button').unbind('click');
            currentPage= pages.eq(current);
            if (current >= pages.length-1)
                current=0;
            else
                current=current+1;
            nextPage = pages.eq(current);   
            currentPage.fadeTo('slow',0.3,function(){
                nextPage.fadeIn('slow',function(){
                    nextPage.css("opacity",1);
                    currentPage.hide();
                    currentPage.css("opacity",1);
                    $('#container .button').bind('click',handler1);             
                }); 
            });
            timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){
                handler2(); 
            }, 8000);
            }
        }

        $('#container .button').click(function(){
            clearTimeout(timeoutID);
            handler1();
        });

        timeoutID=setTimeout(function(){
            handler2(); 
            }, 8000);

});

</script>

<!--GOOGLE TRACKING-->
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-61408930-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!--GOOGLE TRACKING-->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the contact form code referenced in a separate PHP document:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Please use the form.
    echo "Error, please return to last page.";
}
$property = $_SESSION['property'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$spambot = $_POST['spambot'];

if ($spambot != 'Yes') {
    $spambot = 'No';
}

//Validate first
if($spambot == 'No')
{
    echo "Please go back and check the 'I'm not a Spambot' box.";
    exit;
}

if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)||empty($tel)) 
{
    echo "Name, email and phone number are mandatory.";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}


// Email information
$email_from = "boris@agentboris.com";
$email_subject = "Real Estate";
$email_body =

"PROPERTY: $property \n \n".

"NAME: $name\n \n".

"MESSAGE:\n 
$message \n \n ". 

"PHONE NUMBER: $tel\n \n".

"EMAIL: $visitor_email\n \n".

$to = "boris@agentboris.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: ../contact/thankyou.php');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

What is the problem?

You can experience the contact form by visiting this property page and clicking on any of the contact links. Please enter "community test" in the body of the form so that my boss knows its not a real client.

http://agentboris.com/listings/92-park.php

Comment: You are going to need to show more code than that.

Comment: I think you are going to have to show a bit more of your code before anyone can help.

Comment: Whats the code around where you set it; and the code around where you access it?

Comment: @rjdown No problem, see edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, I'd like to advise you not to use `Session` to do that, many users (like me) open multiple pages before viewing, so your property will get just the last one, sending the wrong property to your boss. Instead, you could pass this info via URL variable, changing the href property of the contact button to something like: http://agentboris.com/listings/listing-contact.php?property=55-scholard-ph5 on each page, and use the PHP `$_GET["property"]` in your contact's PHP code. You could use the contact form on each page too.

About the doubt of the solution stop working, make sure you aren't using `@session_destroy()` anywhere, neither resetting it elsewhere, sometimes I do something like: `if (!$_SESSION["property"] = "")` and in reality I'm resetting it to `""`. Certainly you are starting the session in the contact's page, right after `<?php`... you have to start the session to get the variable ok.

Hope it help you! Regards!

PS. you have a beautiful website!

Comment: thanks for the response, i've tried testing this out on a page but its not working, it wont call the ?property=56-berkindle.

Comment: Also, I'm not using @session_destroy anywhere.